# commutator for KG field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator

I am reading Peskin and Schroeder's book, and am wondering about the commutator

$$[\phi(\boldsymbol{x}),\pi(\boldsymbol{y})] = i\delta^{(3)}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}).$$

I do not see the usual commutator relation

$$[A,B] = - [B,A]$$ defined.

Is this relation true for these operators?  Does

$$[\pi(\boldsymbol{x}),\phi(\boldsymbol{y})] = -i\delta^{(3)}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})$$

Comment: What's stopping you from checking it yourself with the expansion of the field?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: That better be true or else it's not a commutator at all!